# Why is Compaq Visual Fortran (CVF) running under WinXP so much faster than gfortran or Intel ifort on Win10Pro 64?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Computer:   intel i7-7820
OS:  Windows 10 pro 64bit  and WinXP pro running in Oracle VM Virtual box
Fortran Compilers:   Compaq Visual Fortran(CVF) Pro. 6.6.C
Intel Fortran ifort version 2024.0.2.27
Gfortran version:   7.3.0

I’ve compiled the exact same source code on three compilers with full optimization on each as 32bit executable.   The code performs 50 timing trials of user specified number of complex fast Fourier transforms (FFT) and then averages the number of FFT’s per second.   The CVF generated code was generated in WinXP Pro running within a VM.   The resultant CVF exe was executed in the XP OS (within the VM) and on the host machine.   The gfortran and Intel generated code was compiled in the Win10Pro 64 OS as 32 bit code.    I’m seeing over an order of magnitude difference in speed between the CVF generated code and that of the Intel and Gfortran generated code.   Am I doing something stupid (I do that on a regular basis) or is this normal??  How can I get CVF speeds with a newer FORTRAN compiler???

Speeds and executable file size:

CVF on XP within VM         37774 FFT/sec                312KB,
CVF on Win10 Pro 64bit          39451FFT/sec                 312KB,
Intel ifort on Win10 Pro 64bit  2588 FFT/sec                  29KB,
Gfortran on Win10 Pro 64bit 2421 FFT/sec                 419 KB,

Source code:

```
c do serial calculation
c
c
c create some fake data
      program main
c
c
      character filename*100
      integer dtstart(8),dtend(8)
      common /ddata/y(16384),n,k,numfft
c
c
c
c      numfft=100000       !number of ffts per threa
      ntrials=50        !number of trials or random timings
c
c find scaling of 0-1.0 random number to 1 to nthmax
c
      write (*,4)
    4 format ('Enter number of ffts per trial')
      read (*,*) numfft
      write (*,8)
    8 format ('Enter output file name (e.g. fftout.txt) ')
      read (*,*) filename
c
c
      open (unit=10,file=filename,
     c      form='formatted',status='unknown')
      write (10,67) numfft,ntrials
   67 format (' GNU Serial Processing  '/i6,4x,'Number of FFTs'/
     ci6,4x,'Number of trials')
c
c  generate fake data
      pi=3.141592653589793
      n=14
      k=2**14
      do 1 j=1,k
    1 y(j)=(1.0*sin(2.0*pi*j/float(k))) + (3.0*sin(20.0*pi*j/float(k)))
c
c loop through the number of trials NTRIALS
c write header
      write (10,6)
    6 format ('total CPU time, clock time,  FFT rate')
c
      sumratcpu=0.0
      sumrattime=0.0
      do 3 itrial=1,ntrials
      write (*,5) itrial
    5 format (//'ITRIAL: ',i5)
c
c      call gettim(ihr0,imin0,isec0,i100th0)
      call cpu_time(timestart)
      call date_and_time(VALUES=dtstart)
c
      ndir=1
      do 88 j=1,numfft
      call fftx(n,k,ndir)
   88 continue
c
c
c      call gettim(ihr1,imin1,isec1,i100th1)
      call cpu_time(timeend)
      call date_and_time(VALUES=dtend)
      deltim=timeend-timestart
      ratcpu=numfft/deltim
c
      tt=(dtend(5)-dtstart(5))*3600 +
     c  (dtend(6)-dtstart(6))*60 +
     c  (dtend(7)-dtstart(7)) +
     c  (dtend(8)-dtstart(7))*0.001
      rattime=numfft/tt
c
      write (10,7) deltim,ratcpu,tt,rattime
      write (*,7) deltim,ratcpu,tt,rattime
    7 format (/'cpu time = ',6x,f10.3,'  fft/sec = ',f10.3/
     c'date_time time = ',f10.3,'  fft/sec = ',f10.3)
c
      sumratcpu=sumratcpu+ratcpu
      sumrattime=sumrattime+rattime
c
    3 continue
      avecpu=sumratcpu/ntrials
      avetime=sumrattime/ntrials
      write (10,2)  avecpu,avetime
      write (*,2)  avecpu,avetime
    2 format ('average rate (cpu)= ',f10.3/
     c'average rate (date_time) = ',f10.3)
      close (unit=10)
c
      stop
      end
      SUBROUTINE FFTX(N,NB,NDIR)
C this rountine was checked on 4/3/94
C NDIR=1  FORWARD TRANSFORM
C NDIR=-1 INVERSE TRANSFORM
C IF NDIR=1 forward  transform
C    INPUT:   A(1)-->A(NB/2+1) ARE signal AMPLITUDEs for positive times
c             if dx=delta x  (i.e. dx=x(n+1)-x(n) then
c             x(1),a(1) corresponds to t=0=0*dx
c             x(2),a(2) corresponds to t=1*dx
c             x(nb/2+1), a(nb/2+1) corresponds to t=(nb/2)*dx
c             x(nb),a(nb) corresponds to t=-1*dx
c             x(nb-1),a(nb-1) corresponds to t=-2*dx
c             x(nb/2+2),a(nb/2+2) corresponds to t=-(nb/2+1)*dx
C    OUTPUT:  A(1)-->A(NB/2+1) ARE +FREQUENCY AMPLITUDE
C             A(NB/2 +2)-->A(NB) -FREQUENCY AMPLITUDE
C             X=FREQUENCies orders as described above
C IF NDIR=-1  forward transform
C   INPUT:   A(1)-->A(NB/2+1) ARE +FREQUENCY AMPLITUDES
C            A(NB/2 + 2)<--A(NB) -FREQUENCY AMPLITUDES
C            X=FREQUENCIES (as described above)
C   OUTPUT:  A(1)-A(NB) TIME AMPLITUDE
C            X(1)-X(NB) TIME (as described above)
c
C
C NOTE:
C  FMAX=1/(DELTA-X)*2=NB/(2*XMAX)
C  DELTAF = 1/XMAX
C  XMAX=NB/2*FMAX
C
      IMPLICIT REAL*4 (A-H,O-Z)
      COMPLEX A(16384),U,W,T
      common /ddata/y(16384),n11,n22,n33
c
c
      do 8 kx=1,nb
    8 a(kx)=cmplx(y(kx),0.0)
c
C REORDER SEQUENCE
      NBD2=NB/2
      NBM1=NB-1
      J=1
      DO 4 L=1,NBM1
      IF (L.GE.J) GO TO 2
      T=A(J)
      A(J)=A(L)
      A(L)=T
    2 K=NBD2
    3 IF (K.GE.J) GO TO 4
      J=J-K
      K=K/2
      GO TO 3
    4 J=J+K
C CALCULATE FFT
      PI=3.141592653589793
      DO 6 M=1,N
      U=CMPLX(1.00,0.00)
      ME=2**M
      K=ME/2
      W=CMPLX(COS(PI/K),-NDIR*SIN(PI/K))
      DO 6 J=1,K
      DO 5 L=J,NB,ME
      LPK=L+K
      T=A(LPK)*U
      A(LPK)=A(L)-T
    5 A(L)=A(L)+T
    6 U=U*W
      RETURN
      END
```

I was expecting newer compilers to generate code comparable in speed to the old CVF compiler.

Comment: You forgot to include the actual options you used with each compiler.

Comment: Former CVF and Intel Fortran developer here, who ran lots of benchmarks comparing the two in the early 2000s. After about 2005, ifort was uniformly faster than CVF in all of the benchmarks I could find, and it got faster each release. I'll note that CVF is restricted to SSE2 instructions, while the Intel compiler can make use of the newer CPUs.  I would like to see the options you used - with Intel I'd suggest /fast as a simple way of gaining even more speed.

Comment: CVF compile:    df commontest.for /exe:ctest.exe

Comment: @SteveLionel   
Simply Fortran(V.3.32):  “Extreme opt.”, 32 bit exe,  2267 FFT/sec.  
Gfortran (v. 13.2.0 ):   -o3 opt. 32bit exe, 2304 FFT/sec.
Intel (in VS v. 2024.0.0.2):  “Maximize Speed plus Higher Level Opt.(/O3)”,  32bit exe, 2579 FFT/sec.
Digital/Compaq Visual Fortran (v. 6.6C):  compiled in WinXP (running within a guest Virtual Box)
“Full Opt.”  run with WinXP(Virtual Box): 36864 FFT/sec
“Full Opt.”  run with Win10 (same exe as above): 39375 FFT/sec
“Maxiumum Opt.” run with WinXP(Virtual Box): 58497 FFT/sec
“Maxiumum Opt. run with Win10 (same exe as above): 62316 FFT/sec

Comment: Thanks for supplying the options.  With gfortran, you can add the `--fast-math` option to get a bit more speed, but that may lead to problems.  You can also add `-march=native`, which will use CPU specific instructions.  However, if I understand you correctly, you have a 64-bit OS and you are compiling the code as a 32-bit application.  This would require the OS to emulate/translate the 32-bit instructions to 64-bit instructions.  What happens if you compile the application as a 64-bit application?

Comment: @SteveLionel  gfortran 64bit with fastmath O3 and match=native  2583 FFT/sec
gfortran 32bit with fastmath O3 and match=native  2612 FFT/sec
gfortran 32bit with fastmath O3  2210 FFT/sec
gfortran 32bit with fastmath  1194 FFT/sec   Not a surprising result but still an order of magnitude slower than the Digital/Compaq results??

Comment: I no longer have a copy of CVF to test, but it reads to me as if you're testing on disparate system environments. Testing on a remote VM isn't the best idea, either.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for the comments.  I'll modify the benchmark to change the input on each loop and will "do something" with the output.   As far as the actual clock time it is obvious --- when I run on anything other than Digital/Compaq I use 10000 FFT/ trial in order to have sufficient time for accurate timing.   When run on Digital/Compaq I have to increase that to 50000.    Yeah, it is legacy code --- I'm an old guy and stuck in my ways --- it is FORTRAN by the way...ha...ha... Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveLionel   I'm building the code under the VM as that is the only way I can get the old compiler to install.  However, all but one of the benchmark runs is performed on the host computer running Win10 pro 64.  Thanks -- I'll incorporate some of Jean-Claude's suggestions and rerun.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Thanks for your input --- modified benchmark using varying inputs on each loop and now I get results that make more sense:   All were compiled as 32bit:   Digital/Compag on WinXP(as guest VM):  1209 FFT/Sec,  Digital/Compaq on Win10 1422 FFT/Sec,  gfortran with -O3 opt. 1975 FFT/sec,  Intel with max. -O3 opt. 2071 FFT/sec.    This makes much more sense.  Thanks Jean-Claude.  However, I will probably continue to use fixed format source code because I'm "old school"...ha...ha.  Thanks again Jean-Claude and Steve